# Portuguese Stack Overflow 404 page has mixed English and Portuguese

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, portuguese-stackoverflow

For reasons unrelated, I browsed to [this user page on the Portuguese Stack Overflow site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/22914). There, I was met by the following:

[image: 404]

See the English in the middle?

That should probably be translated. I also noticed that "Tags" is the same as in English, but really don't know enough Portuguese to be able to tell whether that is right or wrong.

I get the same result in incognito mode as well as in *Lynx*, so this is not my browser doing something fishy or related to my profile.

Comment: **Related:** "Tour" in the "help" drop down menu is titled "Tour".

Comment: OH the freehand. You could perform it better, couldn't you? :)

Comment: @nicael I think he's demonstrated excellent freehand  control. Circles are _cake_ compared to parallel lines.

Comment: @Mooseman Portuguese assimilated the English word, if that's what you're saying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just fixed it.

Translation:

> Veja as ultimas perguntas
>   Veja as tags mais populares