# Portuguese Stack Overflow Help Center is partially translated

Tags: bug, help-center, localization, portuguese-stackoverflow

The Portuguese 404 page is [now fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251647/portugese-stack-overflow-404-page-has-mixed-english-and-portugese) but the [help page](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) is still a mixture of English and Portuguese.

The English titles do [link to translated pages bar the titles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) so translation would seem to be required for the following text on the page:

- Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?
- How do I write a good answer?
- What kind of behavior is expected of users?
- Why is voting important?
- Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?
- How do I delete my account?

Which would then presumably also result in a translation of the titles on the pages that they link to.