# Portuguese Help Center images need to be localized

Tags: bug, help-center, localization, portuguese-stackoverflow

The [Interesting Topics](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) and [Account Deletion](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) pages in the Portuguese Help Center do contain localized text but they also have images that have not been localized.

This example image is from the Portuguese Account Deletion Help Center page

[image: Account Deletion Image]

Comment: The "How do I delete my account?" could be updated too...

Comment: I already raised that one separately: [Portuguese Stack Overflow Help Center is partially translated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251699/portugese-stack-overflow-help-center-is-partially-translated)