# On non-English sites, Flagging dialogs use a mix of English and the native language

Tags: bug, localization, flag-dialog, internationalization

Currently, there seem to be 4 Stack Exchange sites that are **hosted completely in another language** ([Portuguese SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Japanese SO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), and [Russian Language](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)).

However, the post-flagging dialogs use a strange mix of English and the Native language, like so:

[image: Mixed flagifor]

And (click for larger views):
[image: Mixed 2] [image: Mixed 3] [image: Mixed 4]

As a cross-site flagger of spam, it's kind of nice to see the key flags in English, but it does seem counter to the idea of localizing those sites.

And, a [previous bug-report about untranslated text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251647/portuguese-stack-overflow-404-page-has-mixed-english-and-portuguese) was resolved by translating the text.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, it's common problem because each translation are identified by original string.

It means, **we lost previous translations** if SO devs change the string for:

- Fixing typos
- Updating URL
- Improving message

and as a result, some of the strings will be displayed in English.
<sub>(Yes, they don't tell us like "Hey, you should translate again!".)</sub>

Comment: This is (one reason) why using the English interface text as the key to the localization data, although unfortunately common, is a bad idea. It would be much better to use separate internal keys like, say, `flag-type-spam`, `flag-type-abusive`, etc. to identify UI strings, and treat the actual English text as just one translation. [MediaWiki gets it right](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Localisation#Using_messages) (in [many other ways](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Localisation), too).